# Unity3D Scene maximum recommended Size/Vertex count

Tags: unity, scene, open-world

I am about to start making a low-poly open world RPG.

That said what would be too big for a single scene, as in maximum recommended amount of GameObjects/Colliders?

*Sorry for the stupid question but would rather know of any issues now rather than run into them and have to redo/edit whats been done to that point.*

Comment: There's no one threshold here that is best for all games. The best way for you to find what works for the specific game you're making is to test it. Build a quick synthetic scene and pile it full of random objects/colliders - they don't have to be final, just something vaguely representative of the kinds thing you plan to do. Test the scene on your target hardware and profile it to see if the performance is within your goal range. If so, add more. If not, peel back. This way you can empirically establish a budget that works for you.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, that was what i was planning but wondered whether there was anything mentioned by Unity on the issue.